# Sending Inline HTML to Gmail using Python

Tags: python, email, smtp

My objective is to send an email with receipt of purchase made. I have a **.html** file that has the html that I want to send as a receipt. From the tutorial I was following, I wrote this code:

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

host = "smtp.gmail.com"
port = 587
username = "****@gmail.com"
password = "*********"
from_email = username
to_list = ["*****@gmail.com"]

try:
    email_conn = smtplib.SMTP(host, port)
    email_conn.ehlo()
    email_conn.starttls()
    email_conn.login(username,password)
    the_msg = MIMEMultipart("alternative")
    the_msg['Subject'] = "Hello there!"
    the_msg["From"] = from_email
    plain_txt = "Testing the message"
    html_txt = """\
        ------some big html code-------
    
    part_1 = MIMEText(plain_txt,'plain')
    part_2 = MIMEText(plain_txt, "html")

    the_msg.attach(part_1)
    the_msg.attach(part_2)
     
    email_conn.sendmail(from_email, to_list, the_msg.as_string())
    email_conn.quit()
except smtplib.SMTPException:
    print("Error sending message.")
```

But, I am getting problem while running the code. The error says

> Non-ASCII character '\xc2' in file send_email.py on line 27, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details

I searched online and also added

> `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`

in the top of my `.py` file. Now, I am able to send mail but I am not getting any embedded receipt in the mail. Can anybody help with this? I am using Python 2.x